# Changing ROBLOSECURITY Cookie in Selenium

Tags: python, roblox

I am attempting to change the cookie of *.ROBLOSECURITY* on *[www.roblox.com](http://www.roblox.com)*. This is for an attempted robot that will cycle through accounts.

I get the error:

> "selenium.common.exceptions.UnableToSetCookieException: Message: unable to set cookie
> (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.75)"

This is the code so far...

```
with open("CookieList.txt") as CookieFile:
    Cookies = CookieFile.readlines()
    for Cookie in Cookies:
        PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
        driver.get("https://www.roblox.com/games/" + GameID + "/Name/")
        #input("Log into your account in the new browser. Type 'Done' when finished.\n")
        roblocookie = {
            'name': "ROBLOSECURITY",
            'value': Cookie,
        }
        driver.add_cookie(roblocookie)
```

I've tried making "ROBLOSECURITY", ".ROBLOSECURITY" and changing the domains to what it is on the website, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use any of the cookie handling methods in WebDriver, we first need to import the Cookie class. To do that, we use:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Cookie;
```

### Retrieve all cookies

```
// This method gets all the cookies
public Set<Cookie> getAllCookies() {
    return driver.manage().getCookies();
}
```

### Retrieve a named cookie

```
// This method gets a specified cookie
public Cookie getCookieNamed(String name) {
    return driver.manage().getCookieNamed(name);
}
```

### Retrieve the value of a cookie

```
// This method gets the value of a specified cookie
public String getValueOfCookieNamed(String name) {
    return driver.manage().getCookieNamed(name).getValue();
}
```

### Add a cookie

```
// This method adds or creates a cookie
public void addCookie(String name, String value, String domain, String path, Date expiry) {
    driver.manage().addCookie(
    new Cookie(name, value, domain, path, expiry));
}
```

### Add a set of cookies

```
// This method adds set of cookies for a domain
public void addCookiesToBrowser(Set<Cookie> cookies, String domain) {
    for (Cookie c : cookies) {
        if (c != null) {
            if (c.getDomain().contains(domain)){
                driver.manage().addCookie(
                new Cookie(name, value, domain, path, expiry));
            }
        }
    }
    driver.navigate().refresh();
}
```

Part of this answer was taken from [here](https://devqa.io/selenium-create-update-delete-cookies/).

Comment: What language? The question is tagged with Python, but the code examples are not. Is it Java?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to edit a cookie. You would have to delete the cookie, and create a new one.

Delete a cookie:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Navigate to the URL
driver.get("http://www.example.com")
driver.add_cookie({"name": "test1", "value": "cookie1"})
driver.add_cookie({"name": "test2", "value": "cookie2"})

# Delete a cookie with name 'test1'
driver.delete_cookie("test1")
```

Create a cookie:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://www.example.com")

# Adds the cookie into current browser context
driver.add_cookie({"name": "key", "value": "value"})
```